# How to template a function with a mix of non-type template parameters and type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

template<class T, bool did_work>
class Test {
    Test(T input) : field(input), success(did_work) {}
    T field;
    bool success;
};

template<typename A>
void func(std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, bool>> input1, A input2) {}

int main() {}
```

**Output:**

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -ggdb -g3 -Wall test.cpp && ./a.out 
test.cpp:12:51: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, bool did_work> class Test’
   12 | void func(std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, bool>> input1, A input2) {}
      |                                                   ^~~~
test.cpp:12:51: note:   expected a constant of type ‘bool’, got ‘bool’
test.cpp:12:55: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   12 | void func(std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, bool>> input1, A input2) {}
      |                                                       ^~
test.cpp:12:55: error: template argument 5 is invalid
```

I need to be able to pass in `unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, true>>` as well as `unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, false>>`. Is there a way to do this in the function definition without changing the class `Test` definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `template<class T, bool did_work>` `did_work` is a non-type template parameter.  What that means is that instead of passing a type to it, it takes a value.  Since it needs a value, you make a `Test` like `Test<A, true>` or `Test<A, false>`, not `Test<A, bool>`.

For your function you can just add a non-type template parameter to do this for you like

```
template<typename A, bool did_work>
void func(std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, did_work>> input1, A input2) {}
```

Comment: so is there no way around this without defining two instances of the function, one that takes `Test<A, false>` and another taking `Test<A, true>`?

Comment: @ajoseps Just added to the answer showing how to adjust the template to take both.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

template<class T, bool did_work>
class Test {
    Test(T input) : field(input), success(did_work) {}
    T field;
    bool success;
};

template<typename A, bool b = true>
void func(std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, b>> input1, A input2)
{

}

int main() {

}
```

## Update

I mean that you write something like:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, bool did_work>
class Test {
public:
    Test(T input) : field(input), success(did_work) {}
private:
    T field;
    bool success;
};

template<
    typename UnorderedMap
    ,typename A
> requires requires (UnorderedMap map){
    map.size();
}
void func(
    UnorderedMap input1,
    A input2)
{
    std::cout << input1.size();
}

int main() 
{
    using A = int;
    Test<A, true> t{12};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Test<A, true>> map{};
    func(map, 12);

    //this would fail!
    //func(12, 12);
}
```

Comment: But in general you should avoid such strict type requirements. I would go with concepts / constraints or SFINAE if you have some requirements.

Comment: do you mind expanding on the concepts / constraints or SFINAE approach? I'm not too familiar with those

Comment: In addition you should not use "By-Value" parameters for containers - that could be expensive...

Comment: can you expand as to why that might be expensive?

Comment: If you transfer large objects by value you may neey to need to copy a lot of data